# CSS - how to manage multi level categories with hundreds of items?

Tags: html, css

I have four levels of categories which show as dropdowns on mouse hover, but my problem is that these categories and subcategories have hundreds of items and **when I add scroll**, it does not show lower level category on mouse hover.

[image]

Following is the CSS for 3rd level category shown in above picture :

```css
    .third-level-cat {
        max-height: 400px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        direction: rtl;
    }
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: I would recommend you to use some menu js plugin for so complicated multi level menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try `overflow: auto;`

You're using overflow-y: scroll; which means horizontal overflow will be hidden. This could be what is hiding your next sub-menu, which I assume would appear on the right side, however you're not posting complete code.

In any case, you may want to step back and analyze your entire interface/experience. This setup isn't the most responsive, and even in the context of mouse+desktop users there are better ways to search and filter.